# Abrir/Fechar Leitor de Disco (Vbs)

Tags: java

Estou utilizando um código para "abri/fechar a gaveta de disco" contudo ela cria um arquivo na área de trabalho e gostaria de arrumar algum outro meio de resolver isso.

```
package controller;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class disc_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //********Start VBScript code to open cd tray************  
            String a = "Set oWMP = CreateObject(\"WMPlayer.OCX\")" + "\n"
                    + "Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection" + "\n"
                    + "For d = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1" + "\n"
                    + "colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject" + "\n"
                    + "Next" + "\n"
                    + "set owmp = nothing" + "\n"
                    + "set colCDROMs = nothing" + "\n"
                    + "wscript.Quit(0)";
            //********End VBScript code to open cd tray************  

            File myCdTrayOpener = new File("OpenCdTray.vbs");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myCdTrayOpener);
            pw.print(a);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myCdTrayOpener);
            myCdTrayOpener.deleteOnExit();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                //********Start VBScript code to open cd tray************  
                String a = "Set oWMP = CreateObject(\"WMPlayer.OCX\")" + "\n"
                        + "Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection" + "\n"
                        + "For d = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1" + "\n"
                        + "colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject" + "\n"
                        + "colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject" + "\n"
                        + "Next" + "\n"
                        + "set owmp = nothing" + "\n"
                        + "set colCDROMs = nothing" + "\n"
                        + "wscript.Quit(0)";
                //********End VBScript code to open cd tray************  

                File myCdTrayOpener = new File("OpenCdTray.vbs");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myCdTrayOpener);
                pw.print(a);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(myCdTrayOpener);
                myCdTrayOpener.deleteOnExit();

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Por que você não cria o arquivo em outro lugar (diretório temp do usuário, talvez?) e depois apaga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos construtores da classe [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) permite enviar como argumento o diretório onde o arquivo deve ser criado. Tendo isso em mente, basta passar uma `String` contendo o caminho do diretório. Por exemplo:

```
// Estando em ambiente Windows, 'diretorio' terá algo como "C:\Users\FULANO"
String diretorio = System.getProperty("user.home");

File myCdTrayOpener = new File(diretorio, "OpenCdTray.vbs");
```

Nesse caso, a ideia de usar `user.home` veio por você estar chamando o método [`deleteOnExit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29). Como o arquivo será deletado quando a maquina virtual for finalizada, creio que não tenha problemas manter o arquivo temporariamente nesse local.

Também é possível obter o [diretório de dados dos programas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1198911/4056678), se for o caso.

Comment: Realmente! Me tira uma dúvida como eu faço para colocar um código dentro do VBS de tempo de espera? Obrigado!

Comment: Não sei, respondi a dúvida sobre Java.

Comment: Sim, respondeu. Agora isso que perguntei é outro caso. Obrigado!

Comment: Creio que seja melhor você criar uma [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para isto @kholyphoenix1, ao invés de tratar nos comentários de uma resposta ^.^

Comment: Exatamente. Obrigado! :D